# error 1064 on my work, connecting the DB to Eclipse and running a REST Api

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i just started coding and i am having a major bump in my code execution and i think i found out why, i have an error in making the table in mySQL

> ERROR 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')

```
CREATE TABLE `rest_db`.`ordini` (
  `id_ordini` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` INT NULL,
  `id_prodotto` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ordini`),
  CONSTRAINT `id_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `rest_db`.`cliente` ()
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `id_prodotto`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `rest_db`.`prodotto` ()
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

I dont understand what i'm doing wrong. i am trying to create a table containing 2 foreign keys

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the referencing and referenced column names inside the `()` in the foreign key constraints.

```
CREATE TABLE `rest_db`.`ordini` (
  `id_ordini` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_cliente` INT NULL,
  `id_prodotto` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_ordini`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (id_cliente)
    REFERENCES `rest_db`.`cliente` (id_cliente)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_id_prodotto`
    FOREIGN KEY (id_prodotto)
    REFERENCES `rest_db`.`prodotto` (id_prodotto)
    ON DELETE RESTRICT
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```